# Read Pixel values, then compare and set to corresponding value

Tags: c, opencv, pixel

How can I find the difference of current pixel value and the next pixel value of a binary image and then set it to the current pixel using C and opencv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Check this latest [OpenCV tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#accessing-pixel-intensity-values)

or

2 ) Try using `[cvGet2D][2]` function and `[cvSet2D][3]` function.

Here is the pseudocode:

```
for i<image.width:
   for j<image.height:
       current = cvGet2D(array,j,i)
       next = cvGet2D(array,j+1,i+1)
       // set the value
       cvSet2D(array,j+1,i+1,current)
```

Try to implement it.

Below is an example on how to access pixel values and set pixel values to understand usage of above two functions.

```
CvScalar s;
s=cvGet2D(img,i,j);
Int value = s.val[k];
// setting new values
s.val[k]=111;
cvSet2D(img,i,j,s);
```

Comment: Sir, I understand that you get the current pixel value and next pixel value but how can I get the difference between the two? current = cvGet2D(array,j,i)
next = cvGet2D(array,j,i+1)
...

Comment: Rather than hassling someone to help you why don't you try figuring it out yourself or patiently waiting for a response.

Comment: Tom Price, I won't ask this if I haven't try figuring it myself. I didn't see anyone have ask about this and I have no idea how to do it in openCV. All I search is bout reading pixel value and setting value but not difference between pixel. cvAbsDiff parameter is from an image so I can't use it in this case.

Comment: Yes that's fair enough but asking someone every hour for a response is not the way things are done on here. Rather than use open cv you could code it yourself using raw image data wouldn't be that hard to do

Comment: @MizukiKai: The result of `cvGet2D` is a cvScalar, which is an array of four elements. If you know C programming, you know how to access each of element of that array, then how to find their difference etc. For your info, i have added an example which also shows how to get k'th element of cv.Scalar. `Int value = s.val[k]`. (Also, actually i am not good in C programming because i don't use it).